# Autoprefixer Browsers warning when using Babel

Tags: javascript, babeljs, postcss, autoprefixer, gulp-autoprefixer

I have a project and it uses Babel to do all browserslist related options. I am getting the warning when I build:

> ```
> > warn    Replace Autoprefixer browsers option to Browserslist config.  
> > Use browserslist key in package.json or .browserslistrc file.
> > 
> >   Using browsers option can cause errors. Browserslist config can   be
> > used for Babel, Autoprefixer, postcss-normalize and other tools.
> > 
> >   If you really need to use option, rename it to overrideBrowserslist.
> > 
> >   Learn more at:   https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#readme
> > https://twitter.com/browserslist
> ```

There are many examples of this issue on the internet, however, for me, I do not have "autoprefixer", "browsers", or "browserslist" anywhere in my package.json. Gatsby by default uses Babel which uses

```html
{
  "browserslist": [">0.25%", "not dead"]
}
```

in it's package.json, but my project doesn't have it anywhere.

My package.json dependencies for reference:

```html
 "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.15.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.6",
    "@nivo/bar": "^0.61.1",
    "@nivo/pie": "^0.61.1",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.1",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.0.21",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.1.10",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.2",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.3",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.12",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.18",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.11",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.15",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "auth0-js": "^9.18.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "focus-visible": "^4.1.5",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "gatsby": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-image": "^3.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap": "^2.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-catch-links": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-env-variables": "^2.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-force-trailing-slashes": "^1.0.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-axe": "^0.5.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.5.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^5.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-source-datocms": "^3.0.11",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.1.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "logrocket": "^2.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.4",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "pure-react-carousel": "^1.27.8",
    "query-string": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.5",
    "react-awesome-slider": "^4.1.0",
    "react-csv-downloader": "^2.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.9.5",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-inclusive-sortable-table": "^1.1.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.9.1",
    "react-outside-click-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.12",
    "react-share": "^4.4.0",
    "react-storage-hooks": "^4.0.1",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^8.3.3",
    "react-use-form-state": "^0.13.2",
    "searchkit": "^2.3.1-alpha.9",
    "sharp": "^0.29.2",
    "slugify": "^1.6.3",
    "stopword": "^1.0.11",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "swr": "^1.1.0",
    "tiny-async-pool": "^1.0.4",
    "trunc-html": "^1.1.2",
    "unfetch": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.64.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11",
    "zxcvbn": "^4.4.2"
  }
```

and my package.json devDependencies:

```html
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.12.1",
    "@bumped-inc/gatsby-plugin-optional-chaining": "^1.0.0",
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.9.11",
    "@loadable/babel-plugin": "^5.13.2",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^6.1.10",
    "@storybook/react": "6.1.10",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^5.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-gatsby": "^2.4.0",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "cypress": "^8.7.0",
    "cypress-graphql-mock": "^0.5.0-alpha.4",
    "dlv": "^1.1.3",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyser-v2": "^1.1.26",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "is-ci-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "jest-runner-eslint": "^1.0.0",
    "jest-runner-sasslint": "^0.1.3",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "^1.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^12.0.2",
    "mocha": "^8.2.0",
    "mochawesome": "^6.1.1",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^4.2.0",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^5.1.0",
    "neat-csv": "^5.1.0",
    "plop": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier": "^2.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "sass-lint": "^1.13.1",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.10.6"
  }
```